# undefined method `valid?` for "possimus":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Tested code:

```
context 'validations' do
let(:super_campaign){FactoryGirl.create(:super_campaign)}
   context 'package' do
    it "Package should be present" do
     expect(super_campaign.package).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting error like `undefined method "valid?" for "possimus":String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only test that the whole model is valid.  You can test if you have an error for the `package` attribute, though.

```
context 'validations' do
let(:super_campaign){FactoryGirl.create(:super_campaign)}
   context 'package' do
    it "Package should be present" do
     expect(super_campaign).to be_valid
     expect(super_campaign.errors[:package]).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expect(super_campaign).to be_valid # AR object, not it's attribute
```

Comment: you are answering withing 45 seconds, It took me more time to type this answer :(